# Why does my code work in python shell but not when I double click the py file

Tags: python

Why does my python file run perfectly in the IDLE but doesn't work when I double click it. Let me rephrase, My if/else statements never seem to be true even tho they work correctly in the IDLE.

I even broke down ALL my code to the most simple if/else statement to test and make sure I wasn't missing something. Here is the code I broke down. this is the exact code in the py file, again it works in IDLE but not when I double click the py file

```
choice = input('letter: ')
if choice == 'a':
    print ('that is an a')
    input('press any key to exit...')
else:
    print('that letter is not an a')
    input('press any key to exit')
```

btw python v3.2
windows 7

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get a stack trace or weird behavior?

Comment: What is the program that opens when you double click? Is it a python 3.2 command line?

Comment: no trace, it just defaults to my else statement

Comment: When you added more print statements, what did you learn?

Comment: actually that wasn't my real program, my real program was a full interface that used classes and functions but my selection screen wasn't working so I had to grind it down to the core and found out it was my if/else statement that wasn't working..all in all i learned to add .strip() until i learn more of how to prevent this in a easier way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding

```
choice = choice.strip()
```

this works for me

```
choice = input('letter: ')
choice = choice.strip()
if choice == 'a':
    print ('that is an a')
    input('press any key to exit...')
else:
    print('that letter is not an a')
    input('press any key to exit')
```

otherwise your `input` gives you the letter together with a newline and the `if` fails

Comment: That did indeed work, without being a hag can u give me a reason why that happened so I'll know for future reference!

Comment: because when you write in the shell 'a'+'enter' input gets both keystrokes and returns 'a\n'.

Answer (score 1):

input()  might be getting a string with a line ending.

Try adding the line `print(repr(choice))` right after the input, to see exactly what you're working with.

Comment: i didnt get to check this as the advice above u seemed to works...BUT THANK YOU SOOO MUCH FOR ALL THE QUICK RESPONSES, i signed up just 3 minutes ago because I couldn't find help on this anywhere...This is now my official python lobby!

Comment: If strip() fixed it, I am correct, and you were getting a line ending.